# C# Selenium - Explicitly waiting By.CssSelector(...)

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am doing an explicit wait with a TimeSpan of 30 seconds and  wait.Until(By.CssSelector("#content .data-grid > .data-row")).

I obviously have a data-grid that is being populated here.

**Result:**

> The wait.Until(...) is returned right away (it does not wait for this CssSelector to evaluate with satisfactory results).

**Expected result:**

> I expect there to be a wait until the data is asynchronously returned.

**Is this a valid scenario for explicitly waiting?**

```
wait.Until(By.CssSelector("#content .data-grid > .data-row"))
```

Comment: What is your question? If this is a valid scenario?

Comment: I updated the question with clarification. Thanks.

Comment: Is your datagrid populated asynchronous? Does your code do the job?

Comment: Yes, the code does work just fine. The issue is that the wait.Until(...) is returning right away. This makes me believe that the wait.Until(CssSelector...) is not valid. Note that there are no rows until the data is returned.

Comment: Okay, then you should wait, for the elements by xpath best. This way you can define the elements that are only there, when the datagrid is populated.

Comment: Isn't this essentially similar to what im doing now? Im checking if datagrid is populated by CssSelector (instead of XPath).

Comment: Do you use FindElement() or FindElements()?

Comment: Use FindElement(), if you want to ensure an element is there.

Comment: don't you need to add a .isPresent() or isVisible()?

Comment: It looks like the html structure is there on page load (the .data-row), or at least a part of it, and on data retrieval it's just filled in. Can you extend the question with - the html before the data is received, and after it?

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Which Framework do you use? dotnet Core or dotnet-framework?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the [`ExpectedConditions`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions.htm)...

You declare the `wait`:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver.driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
```

Then you add `ExpectedConditions` here I am using [`ElementIsVisible`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions_ElementIsVisible.htm) for the example:

```
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.CssSelector("#content .data-grid > .data-row")));
```

Hope this does the trick!